# Unity 3d won't work on an Nvidia Ion

Tags: 11.10, unity, hdmi, nvidia

On a ZBOX HD-ND22 with ion GPU instead of unity 3d i always get unity 2d. When booting from a live cd it works but it's using the noveau driver which has no hdmi sound.

I have tried this command for compatibility test: /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p

The output is:

```
OpenGL vendor string:   NVIDIA Corporation  
OpenGL renderer string: ION/PCI/SSE2  
OpenGL version string:  3.3.0 NVIDIA 280.13

Not software rendered:    yes  
Not blacklisted:          yes  
GLX fbconfig:             yes  
GLX texture from pixmap:  yes  
GL npot or rect textures: yes  
GL vertex program:        yes  
GL fragment program:      yes  
GL vertex buffer object:  yes  
GL framebuffer object:    yes  
GL version is 1.4+:       yes  

Unity 3D supported:       yes  
Segmentation Fault
```

It looks good until the segmentetion fault. In the test i had run in live cd mode this wasn't present.
has anyone an idea how to solve this problem?

- I have tried both, version current and version current-updates of the nvidia driver

Comment: Did you install any drivers so far?

Comment: Yes i need the nvidia drivers for hdmi audio output, i have tried both, version current and version current-updates.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://askubuntu.com/questions/76222/are-the-nvidia-drivers-not-performing-as-they-should

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i found the error, as i wanted to use tmpfs for /tmp, i added this line to /etc/fstab:

```
tmpfs /tmp tmpfs defaults,noexec,nosuid 0 0
```

After removing this unity 3d works as it should with the nvidia driver.